# getting exception while running servlet program in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:299)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:288)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:287)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:422)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:355)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil.<clinit>(UpgradeUtil.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:50)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
```

//what does these exception mean ? ?? ? ?
//what should i do in order to resolve these exceptions? ? ? ?

Comment: Actually , you pasted the stacktrace from middle. Show full stacktrace.

Comment: Like Suresh said, this is just the middle of it. The real exception thrown isn't shown here. It's just showing the call stack before the exception was thrown. On application servers the call stacks tend to be quite long, so you shouldn't get intimidated by the wall of text. It's still just one error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to redo your environmental PATH Variable pointing to where your JDK is located again.

[The link will show you how to reset it.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Answer (score 0):

set classpath `servlet-api.jar`
 you will find in tomcat lib folder

```
 Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar
```